# Replace labels of datatable in a chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-analytics

I am populating a [Area chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) from the `datatable` returned by
Analytics API, but the labels of the columns are populated with the name of the metrics.

The aim is to make it easier to read, then looking for a way to replace the value of the label, I found the `ticks`, but had no effect:

```
'ticks' => [ ['v' => 'ga:goalsCompletionsAll', 'f' => 'Objetivos completados'] ],
```

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_conversion);

function drawChart_conversion() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable("{\"cols\":[{\"id\":\"ga:date\",\"label\":\"ga:date\",\"type\":\"date\"},{\"id\":\"ga:sessions\",\"label\":\"ga:sessions\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"id\":\"ga:pageviews\",\"label\":\"ga:pageviews\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"id\":\"ga:goalCompletionsAll\",\"label\":\"ga:goalCompletionsAll\",\"type\":\"number\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 21)\"},{\"v\":\"20912\"},{\"v\":\"60184\"},{\"v\":\"6386\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 20)\"},{\"v\":\"27073\"},{\"v\":\"70853\"},{\"v\":\"7425\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 19)\"},{\"v\":\"27603\"},{\"v\":\"79345\"},{\"v\":\"8738\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 18)\"},{\"v\":\"27830\"},{\"v\":\"84522\"},{\"v\":\"9350\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 17)\"},{\"v\":\"29514\"},{\"v\":\"77769\"},{\"v\":\"7936\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 16)\"},{\"v\":\"30244\"},{\"v\":\"82223\"},{\"v\":\"8605\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 15)\"},{\"v\":\"33329\"},{\"v\":\"89677\"},{\"v\":\"9227\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 14)\"},{\"v\":\"35109\"},{\"v\":\"97420\"},{\"v\":\"10222\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 13)\"},{\"v\":\"28073\"},{\"v\":\"65107\"},{\"v\":\"5984\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 12)\"},{\"v\":\"29413\"},{\"v\":\"69381\"},{\"v\":\"6604\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 11)\"},{\"v\":\"36198\"},{\"v\":\"95145\"},{\"v\":\"9865\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 10)\"},{\"v\":\"40324\"},{\"v\":\"101335\"},{\"v\":\"10038\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 09)\"},{\"v\":\"42686\"},{\"v\":\"92811\"},{\"v\":\"8538\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 08)\"},{\"v\":\"28007\"},{\"v\":\"81052\"},{\"v\":\"8973\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 07)\"},{\"v\":\"28904\"},{\"v\":\"80751\"},{\"v\":\"8635\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 06)\"},{\"v\":\"23209\"},{\"v\":\"65989\"},{\"v\":\"7249\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 05)\"},{\"v\":\"22088\"},{\"v\":\"59370\"},{\"v\":\"6216\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 04)\"},{\"v\":\"29197\"},{\"v\":\"85678\"},{\"v\":\"9060\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 03)\"},{\"v\":\"30952\"},{\"v\":\"95124\"},{\"v\":\"10687\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 02)\"},{\"v\":\"33903\"},{\"v\":\"101749\"},{\"v\":\"11771\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 02, 01)\"},{\"v\":\"30964\"},{\"v\":\"83933\"},{\"v\":\"8927\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 29)\"},{\"v\":\"28980\"},{\"v\":\"85747\"},{\"v\":\"9282\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 28)\"},{\"v\":\"22790\"},{\"v\":\"61742\"},{\"v\":\"6594\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 27)\"},{\"v\":\"21750\"},{\"v\":\"58801\"},{\"v\":\"6404\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 26)\"},{\"v\":\"13476\"},{\"v\":\"39905\"},{\"v\":\"4441\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 25)\"},{\"v\":\"21799\"},{\"v\":\"58781\"},{\"v\":\"6350\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 24)\"},{\"v\":\"32734\"},{\"v\":\"91558\"},{\"v\":\"9594\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 23)\"},{\"v\":\"32281\"},{\"v\":\"96403\"},{\"v\":\"10349\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 22)\"},{\"v\":\"37484\"},{\"v\":\"105435\"},{\"v\":\"11150\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 21)\"},{\"v\":\"29868\"},{\"v\":\"81317\"},{\"v\":\"8537\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2016, 01, 20)\"},{\"v\":\"28819\"},{\"v\":\"81865\"},{\"v\":\"8759\"}]}]}");
  var chart_div = document.getElementById('googlechart_conversion');
  var options = {
    "hAxis": {
      "titleTextStyle": {
        "color": "#333"
      },
      "gridlines": {
        "color": "transparent"
      }
    },
    "vAxis": {
      "ticks": [{
        "v": "ga:pageviews",
        "f": "teste"
      }],
      "minValue": 0
    },
    "pointsVisible": true,
    "        pointSize": 5,
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "200",
    "chartArea": {
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "80%"
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(chart_div);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="googlechart_conversion"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) to get a list of all public dimensions and metrics and then loop through your API response and swap them out.

The `<google-analytics-chart>` polymer element does exactly this, so you could take a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-analytics/blob/master/google-analytics-chart.html#L376-L387) to get an idea of how it works.

To make some of this easier for you, you could use the Google Analytics [javascript-api-utils](https://github.com/googleanalytics/javascript-api-utils) module, which adds some nice convenience methods for querying the Metadata API (e.g. caching the results, filtering my dimensions/metrics/public/private, etc.).